# how to execute a url or hyperlink without leaving the existing page using asp.net

Tags: c#

I have used this code

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
byte[] reqHTML;
reqHTML = webClient.DownloadData(url);
```

for executing a url. Here i am having a question, while using this code, whether the cookies set or not?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are not sent by default with WebClient. You could although write your implementation that uses a [cookie container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.cookiecontainer.aspx):

```
public class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient  
{  
    private CookieContainer _container = new CookieContainer();  

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)  
    {  
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);  

        if (request is HttpWebRequest)  
            ((HttpWebRequest)request).CookieContainer = _container;  

        return request;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the cookies from the ASP.NET page that is executing - then no: I'm pretty sure that `WebClient` is not going to look **at all** for the cookies on the current executing web request.

If you want this functionality, can you perhaps use AJAX from the browser? Perhaps via jQuery? That should flow the context etc as per standard browser rules.

Alternatively, you are going to have to handle the cookies yourself (i.e. copy them into the `WebClient`, and back if needed).